# System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException in MVC projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In all MVC projects that I can remember (I'm now on version 3) I get the error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

appearing in the Debug Output pane when the project is run. Thus far I have ignored it because it seemed to make no difference, but ultimately I don't like errors appearing even if they have no apparent effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All exceptions are appearing in Debug mode, even those that are handled. When an exception is thrown in Debug model Visual Studio stops the execution and alerts you for this exception even if it is properly handled by your code. If a [first chance exception](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx) is properly handled you can safely ignore it. You can [disable first chance exceptions](http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/24) in Visual Studio.

Comment: Nice to know that first chance exceptions can be ignored, particularly since they are not in my code.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if was a issue only in my machine, but enabling the following config, solved the case.

Debug -> Options -> Debugging and check Enable Just My Code (Managed Only)

[StackOverflow Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741968/visual-studio-2012-rc-breaks-on-exceptions-from-within-the-net-framework-how-d#answer-11742225)