# Visual Studio 2012 RC breaks on exceptions from within the .NET Framework. How do I make it break on exceptions only in my code?

Tags: .net, debugging, exception, visual-studio-2012

When debugging using Visual Studio 2012 RC with break on exception turned on, Visual Studio breaks on exceptions from within the .NET Framework. How do I make it break on exceptions only in my code?

When debugging a ASP.NET MVC 4 project there are a lot of framework exceptions thrown on every page hit. The following exception happens a lot:

```
System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException occurred
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: name
UserCache is an invalid culture identifier.
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=name
  InvalidCultureName=UserCache
  StackTrace:
       at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(String name, Boolean useUserOverride)
  InnerException:
```

This exception is coming from within mscorlib.dll which I do not not want Visual Studio to break on.

It looks like I am missing a column in the exceptions window. I only see the "Thrown" column and "User-Unhandled" is missing. This might be my issue.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is go to

Debug -> Options -> Debugging and check **Enable Just My Code (Managed Only)**

Comment: In my case (Based on environment settings) this option was available under Tools > Options > Debugging > General > check Enable Just My Code (Managed Only)

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Debug* -> *Exceptions* and untick everything. This will tell the debugger to break only on exceptions which are not handled. Unhandled exceptions are ones which are not 'caught', which do not happen within an appropriate try/catch.

But understand that whichever type of exception happens, if it is not handled, either the debugger will break or application will exit. That's how it's supposed to work. If you expect the exception to happen, wrap culprit code in appropriate try/catch block.

In this case that would be

```
try
{
...
}
catch (CultureNotFoundException ex)
{
   // Show your own message here, or otherwise handle the exception
}
```

Comment: I want to it to break on handled exceptions in my code not just unhandled ones.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. In that case tick **Common Language Runtime Exceptions**.

Comment: It is already ticked. When ticked it breaks on all exceptions within the .NET Framework. Unticked it doesn't break on anything.